# Leaflet: Difference between map panning and dragging

Tags: leaflet, user-experience

What does map.dragging do and what is the difference to the pan functionality of the map?
Or is dragging = true enabling the panning of the map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To *pan* is to change what part of the map the user is looking at; this is derived from the [meaning of "pan" in cinematography](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pan#Etymology_2): moving the camera so the viewport changes.

In Leaflet, you can pan the map non-interactively, by calling `map.panTo()` and `map.panBy()` and `map.setCenter()` on your `map` instance (but those are not the only ways to pan a map).

To *drag* [means](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/drag#Verb) "to pull along a surface". In computing, it refers to the [drag and drop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_and_drop) interaction. It implies user interaction.

In Leaflet, a map drag is the *user action* of using a pointing device in a down-move-up sequence on the viewport surface. The map pans as the user drags.

**A map drag implies a map pan; but a map pan does not imply a map drag.**

Also, note that Leaflet allows markers to be draggable. Thus, one can perform a marker drag, an action that is not a map drag, and does not imply a map pan.

Comment: Hi Ivan, thanks a lot for your detailed explanation! As summary, correct me if i got it wrong: If map draggable = false I can still pan programmatically with e.g. the mentioned methods but not by user interaction "dragging" the map with a pointer.

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: on Leaflet map 
const  map = L.map("map").setView([31.505, -0.09], 7);

do we need to enable or by Default the dragging is enabled? 
And even I had changed the 'map.dragging.enable() still I am unable to drag (mouse-down and move along)